# How to give tokens from certain tokenizers more weight?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following (simplified) data

```json
[
  { id: 1, customerNumber: "0008", name: "Bob" },
  { id: 2, customerNumber: "0854", name: "Sue" },
  { id: 3, customerNumber: "0041", name: "Larry" }
]
```

The context is a auto-complete search bar at the top of an application.

I'm using a custom regex tokenizer to trim the leading zeros so that the user need not enter them. So that gets me the tokens

```
ID 1 => "8"
ID 2 => "854"
ID 3 => "41"
```

I also have an edge-n-gram tokenizer applied which gives me the tokens

```
ID 1 => "8"
ID 2 => "854", "85", "8"
ID 3 => "41", "4"
```

Our users consider "0008" a better match for the query "8" than "0854". But when they search for "8" they are getting tons of results like "08**" ranking higher than "0008".

**How do I make "0008" rank higher than "0854" when searching for "8"?**

- Sometimes the users will include the leading zeros in their query.
- I think the problem is that both id 1 and 2 tokenize to a single "8" so from there on they are equal. I just don't know how to remedy that problem.

Query:

```
POST _search
{
    "size": 24,
    "from": 0,
    "query": { 
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "8",
            "fields": [
                "customerNumber",
                "name"
            ],
            "type": "best_fields"
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up achieving my desired result by changing my "leading zeros trimmer" from a "Token Filter" to a "Character Filter".

I also changed the "Edge N Gram *Token Filter*" I was using to be an "Edge N Gram *Tokenizer*" instead.

These two changes together gave me my desired result.

Comment: can you dd you query here?